# Fixing illogical "incompatibility components" error copied from OpenModelica Library

Tags: modelica, openmodelica

I am trying to model and replicate the "Open Brayton Power Cycle" from the OpenModelica Library and have come across an error message that makes little sense. The error message is the result of incompatibility between sourceMassflow.mo and CombustionChamber.mo, all taken from the modelica library and connected in the same fashion as the library Brayton example has been done.

This error has occurred after completely replicating the "Brayton Power Cycle - Open" from the modelica library.

This is the error I am receiving. This message almost proves that the two components are compatible with one another however I cannot figure out the reason why they are "not working" together.

```
[11] 14:18:40 Translation Error
[BraytonCycle_First: 49:3-50:84]: Incompatible components in connect statement: connect(sourceMassFlow1.flange, combustionChamber1.inf)
- sourceMassFlow1.flange has components {C_outflow, Xi_outflow, h_outflow, m_flow, p}
- combustionChamber1.inf has components {C_outflow, Xi_outflow, h_outflow, m_flow, p}
```

I copied all of the library's component parameters into my model and expected this to solve the issue. Nothing I have done fixes this issue, where it seems that these models would be compatible due to the error message above.

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This looks like a bug. Can you share the model?

Comment: Sure I can. What do you think is the best way to do so? Copy and pasting the entire script?

Comment: If you mean the entire .mo files you use, then yes. You could open a bug at our Trac and attach the .mo files there:
https://trac.openmodelica.org/OpenModelica/newticket

Comment: Below I've attached information directing you to the ticket of my .mo file.

https://trac.openmodelica.org/OpenModelica/ticket/5331

Comment: Thanks. I will look into it.

Comment: @AdrianPop Not to beat the horse to death, but I switched my focus onto the Rankine cycle in hopes for a better outcome. However, I'm getting the same type of incompatibility error, except with a statereader_gas.mo component with a he.mo (heatexchanger) component as well. It's just really confusing because this model with compatibility errors is being derived from the OpenModelica Library Examples.

Comment: The problem is with the redeclares you (need to) have for the medium inside the connectors. It needs to be the same medium on both sides of the connect and also you need to use the mediums from ThermoPower.Media not the ones in Modelica.Media.

Answer (score 3):

This model compiles but has issues with simulation. Maybe you can fix those. I changed all the redeclares to use ThermoPower.Media.* mediums.

```
model BraytonCycleLibraryReplica "Brayton Cycle iterations with re-declared mediums and copied values from Library Plant"

//Figure out the importance of table values//
  parameter Real tableEtaC[6, 4]=[0, 95, 100, 105; 1, 82.5e-2, 81e-2,
      80.5e-2; 2, 84e-2, 82.9e-2, 82e-2; 3, 83.2e-2, 82.2e-2, 81.5e-2; 4,
      82.5e-2, 81.2e-2, 79e-2; 5, 79.5e-2, 78e-2, 76.5e-2];
  parameter Real tablePhicC[6, 4]=[0, 95, 100, 105; 1, 38.3e-3, 43e-3,
      46.8e-3; 2, 39.3e-3, 43.8e-3, 47.9e-3; 3, 40.6e-3, 45.2e-3, 48.4e-3;
      4, 41.6e-3, 46.1e-3, 48.9e-3; 5, 42.3e-3, 46.6e-3, 49.3e-3];
  parameter Real tablePR[6, 4]=[0, 95, 100, 105; 1, 22.6, 27, 32; 2, 22,
      26.6, 30.8; 3, 20.8, 25.5, 29; 4, 19, 24.3, 27.1; 5, 17, 21.5, 24.2];
  parameter Real tablePhicT[5, 4]=[1, 90, 100, 110; 2.36, 4.68e-3, 4.68e-3,
      4.68e-3; 2.88, 4.68e-3, 4.68e-3, 4.68e-3; 3.56, 4.68e-3, 4.68e-3,
      4.68e-3; 4.46, 4.68e-3, 4.68e-3, 4.68e-3];
  parameter Real tableEtaT[5, 4]=[1, 90, 100, 110; 2.36, 89e-2, 89.5e-2,
      89.3e-2; 2.88, 90e-2, 90.6e-2, 90.5e-2; 3.56, 90.5e-2, 90.6e-2,
      90.5e-2; 4.46, 90.2e-2, 90.3e-2, 90e-2];

  ThermoPower.Gas.Turbine turbine1(
  redeclare package Medium = ThermoPower.Media.FlueGas, 
  Ndesign = 157.08, 
  Table = ThermoPower.Choices.TurboMachinery.TableTypes.matrix, 
  Tdes_in = 1400, 
  Tstart_in = 1370, 
  Tstart_out = 800, 
  pstart_in = 7.85e5, 
  pstart_out = 1.52e5, tableEta = tableEtaT, tablePhic = tablePhicT) 
  annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {40, -8}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));

  ThermoPower.Gas.Compressor compressor1(
  redeclare package Medium = ThermoPower.Media.Air, 
  Ndesign = 157.08, 
  Table = ThermoPower.Choices.TurboMachinery.TableTypes.matrix, 
  Tdes_in = 244.4, 
  Tstart_in = 244.4, 
  Tstart_out = 600.4, 
  explicitIsentropicEnthalpy = true, 
  pstart_in = 0.343e5, 
  pstart_out = 8.3e5, tableEta = tableEtaC, tablePR = tablePR, tablePhic = tablePhicC) 
  annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-40, -8}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));

  ThermoPower.Gas.CombustionChamber combustionChamber1(
  Cm = 1, 
  HH = 41.6e6, 
  S = 0.05, 
  Tstart = 1370, 
  V = 0.05, 
  gamma = 1, 
  initOpt = ThermoPower.Choices.Init.Options.steadyState, 
  pstart = 8.11e5) 
  annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {0, 30}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));

  ThermoPower.Gas.PressDrop pressDrop1(
  redeclare package Medium = ThermoPower.Media.Air, A = 1, FFtype = ThermoPower.Choices.PressDrop.FFtypes.OpPoint, Tstart = 600, dpnom = 19000, pstart = 8.3e5, rhonom = 4.7, wnom = 100) 
  annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-32, 14}, extent = {{-6, -6}, {6, 6}}, rotation = -90)));

  ThermoPower.Gas.PressDrop pressDrop2(
  redeclare package Medium = ThermoPower.Media.FlueGas, 
  FFtype = ThermoPower.Choices.PressDrop.FFtypes.OpPoint, 
  Tstart = 1370, 
  dpnom = 26000, 
  pstart = 811000, 
  rhonom = 2, 
  wnom = 102) 
  annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {32, 14}, extent = {{-6, -6}, {6, 6}}, rotation = -90)));

  ThermoPower.Gas.SourceMassFlow sourceMassFlow1(
  redeclare package Medium = ThermoPower.Media.NaturalGas, T = 300, p0 = 811000, use_in_w0 = true, w0 = 2.02) 
  annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-44, 40}, extent = {{-6, -6}, {6, 6}}, rotation = 0)));

  ThermoPower.Gas.SourcePressure sourcePressure1(
  redeclare package Medium = ThermoPower.Media.Air, 
  T = 244.4, 
  p0 = 34300) 
  annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-92, 0}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));

  ThermoPower.PowerPlants.HRSG.Components.StateReader_gas stateReader_gas1(
  redeclare package Medium = ThermoPower.Media.Air) 
  annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-22, 30}, extent = {{-8, -8}, {8, 8}}, rotation = 0)));

  ThermoPower.PowerPlants.HRSG.Components.StateReader_gas stateReader_gas2(
  redeclare package Medium = ThermoPower.Media.FlueGas) 
  annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {22, 30}, extent = {{-8, -8}, {8, 8}}, rotation = 0)));

  Modelica.Blocks.Continuous.FirstOrder firstOrder1(
  T = 4, 
  initType = Modelica.Blocks.Types.Init.SteadyState, 
  y_start = 500) 
  annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-85, 51}, extent = {{-5, -5}, {5, 5}}, rotation = 0)));

  Modelica.Blocks.Interfaces.RealInput FuelFlowRate
  annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-142, 18}, extent = {{-20, -20}, {20, 20}}, rotation = 0), iconTransformation(origin = {-142, 18}, extent = {{-20, -20}, {20, 20}}, rotation = 0)));

  ThermoPower.Gas.SinkPressure sinkPressure1(
  redeclare package Medium = ThermoPower.Media.FlueGas, 
  T = 800, 
  p0 = 1.52e5) 
  annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {66, 20}, extent = {{-6, -6}, {6, 6}}, rotation = 0)));

  Modelica.Mechanics.Rotational.Sensors.PowerSensor powerSensor1 
  annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {60, -8}, extent = {{-6, -6}, {6, 6}}, rotation = 0)));

  ThermoPower.Electrical.Generator generator1(
  J = 30, 
  initOpt = ThermoPower.Choices.Init.Options.steadyState,
  shaft(phi(start=0, fixed=true))) 
  annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {80, -8}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));

  Modelica.Blocks.Continuous.FirstOrder firstOrder2(
  T = 1, 
  initType = Modelica.Blocks.Types.Init.SteadyState, 
  k = 1, 
  y_start = 56.8e6) 
  annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {80, -36}, extent = {{-6, -6}, {6, 6}}, rotation = 0)));

  Modelica.Blocks.Interfaces.RealOutput GeneratedPower 
  annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {106, 16}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0), iconTransformation(origin = {106, 16}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));

  ThermoPower.Electrical.NetworkGrid_Pmax networkGrid_Pmax1(
  J = 30000, 
  Pmax = 10e6, 
  deltaStart = 0.4, 
  initOpt = ThermoPower.Choices.Init.Options.steadyState)  
  annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {106, -8}, extent = {{-8, -8}, {8, 8}}, rotation = 0)));
  inner ThermoPower.System system annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-130, 70}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));
equation
  connect(firstOrder2.y, GeneratedPower) annotation(
    Line(points = {{86, -36}, {92, -36}, {92, 16}, {106, 16}, {106, 16}}, color = {0, 0, 127}));
  connect(powerSensor1.power, firstOrder2.u) annotation(
    Line(points = {{56, -14}, {56, -36}, {73, -36}}, color = {0, 0, 127}));
  connect(powerSensor1.flange_b, generator1.shaft) annotation(
    Line(points = {{66, -8}, {72, -8}, {72, -8}, {72, -8}}));
  connect(turbine1.shaft_b, powerSensor1.flange_a) annotation(
    Line(points = {{46, -8}, {54, -8}, {54, -8}, {54, -8}, {54, -8}}));
  connect(turbine1.outlet, sinkPressure1.flange) annotation(
    Line(points = {{48, 0}, {48, 0}, {48, 20}, {60, 20}, {60, 20}}, color = {159, 159, 223}));
  connect(sourcePressure1.flange, compressor1.inlet) annotation(
    Line(points = {{-82, 0}, {-48, 0}, {-48, 0}, {-48, 0}}, color = {159, 159, 223}));
  connect(firstOrder1.y, sourceMassFlow1.in_w0) annotation(
    Line(points = {{-80, 52}, {-48, 52}, {-48, 44}, {-48, 44}, {-48, 44}}, color = {0, 0, 127}));
  connect(sourceMassFlow1.flange, combustionChamber1.inf) annotation(
    Line(points = {{-38, 40}, {0, 40}, {0, 40}, {0, 40}}, color = {159, 159, 223}));
  connect(FuelFlowRate, firstOrder1.u) annotation(
    Line(points = {{-142, 18}, {-100, 18}, {-100, 51}, {-91, 51}}, color = {0, 0, 127}));
  connect(pressDrop2.outlet, turbine1.inlet) annotation(
    Line(points = {{32, 8}, {32, 8}, {32, 0}, {32, 0}}, color = {159, 159, 223}));
  connect(pressDrop1.outlet, compressor1.outlet) annotation(
    Line(points = {{-32, 8}, {-32, 8}, {-32, 0}, {-32, 0}}, color = {159, 159, 223}));
  connect(stateReader_gas2.outlet, pressDrop2.inlet) annotation(
    Line(points = {{26, 30}, {32, 30}, {32, 20}, {32, 20}}, color = {159, 159, 223}));
  connect(combustionChamber1.out, stateReader_gas2.inlet) annotation(
    Line(points = {{10, 30}, {18, 30}, {18, 30}, {18, 30}}, color = {159, 159, 223}));
  connect(stateReader_gas1.outlet, combustionChamber1.ina) annotation(
    Line(points = {{-18, 30}, {-10, 30}, {-10, 30}, {-10, 30}}, color = {159, 159, 223}));
  connect(pressDrop1.inlet, stateReader_gas1.inlet) annotation(
    Line(points = {{-32, 20}, {-32, 20}, {-32, 30}, {-26, 30}, {-26, 30}}, color = {159, 159, 223}));
  connect(compressor1.shaft_b, turbine1.shaft_a) annotation(
    Line(points = {{-34, -8}, {34, -8}}));
  annotation(
    uses(ThermoPower(version = "3.1"), Modelica(version = "3.2.2")));
end BraytonCycleLibraryReplica;
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked like you said, a small detail a novice modelica user would overlook/not realize. You are a gentleman and a scholar for being so proactive on the stackoverflow community as well as the OpenModelica Forum. Being an avid user of both platforms I recognize your presence and help on both of these forums.